Connecting to Cluster not working in Private Network
I have two VPS in same Private Network
Service running on 10.0.0.1
Redis Server running on 10.0.0.3 (bind 0.0.0.0 in redis.conf)

Try connect using createClient to one Master then connect to be successful
Try connect using Redis Insight use SSH Tunnel or direct with firewall disabled then connect to be successful
Try connect using createCluster to one Master or three Master or all Master and Slave then return error
Redis Client Error ECONNREFUSED: Failed to connect errno: 24  syscall: "connect"

Tested on two node-redis versions 4.6.15 and 4.7.0
Service can connect to Redis cluster server
